# Scaling autocorrelated features

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, autocorrelation, normalization, feature-scaling

If I have a bunch of autocorrelated features (for example, temperature, rainfall) that I want to use to predict a dependent variable, how should I scale these autocorrelated features before passing them through a time-series model?

Generally, I have seen people using mean and standard deviation for scaling, but since autocorrelated data aren't independent observations by definition how's the use of standard deviation valid?

Comment: you can scale all the same, autocorrelation has no bearing in this

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if I use standard deviation for normalizing, then it's invalid because estimation of standard deviation assumes independent observations

Comment: it's not like scaling is a brain surgery, it's to get the values to about the same order of magnitude to make it easier on the numerical optimization routines, don't sweat about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not worry about autocorrelation in feature scaling. Feature scaling is a numerical, not a statistical issue. Statistically, estimating the standard deviation from an autocorrelated time series requires special adjustments. Numerically, you just want the numbers to be on roughly the same scale for stability of algorithms.

Comment: Some methods aren't scale-invariant. This can become problematic for variables with large-scale differences in variance. Below are methods sensitive to scaling,Scaling impacts, 
1. Algorithms optimized through Gradient Descent - Neural Network
2. Clustering algorithms that are distance-based (KNN, K-means, Hierarchical Clustering)
3. Dimensionality Reduction (Principal Component Analysis)